# Automated UML2 Class Diagram generation from SQL?

Tags: database-design, scripting

How can I generate a class diagram from an SQL database or script?  I'll add the functions and set whether the attributes are public, private or virtual once the initial diagram is generated.

I've generated it using [PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner), here is the .sql file: http://pastebin.com/S14JWjKF

Comment: Have you already generated UML using PowerDesigner? Or used PowerDesigner to generate the SQL script? Not clear what you're asking Surely you can generate UML from PowerDesigner because your conceptial model is in PowerDesigner, not SQL. Like I'd use ORM http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/is-there-any-good-tool-for-making-database-design-and-prototypes/1678#1678

Comment: Looks like I can build an OO model straight from the ER Diagram in PowerDesigner. This one however, doesn't have the getter and setter operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

1. Generate SQL file in PowerDesigner (or any other tool capable of
   generating SQL, or write it by hand)
2. Install Eclipse with JPA and Modelling Tools
3. Follow this guide
4. When the guide fails you (step 4), open up another tool (or you
   could probably do it in Eclipse with a new project), for instance,
   PowerDesigner; and reverse-engineer the Java code into a Class
   diagram
5. Profit!

:D

Comment: "3. Folow this guide"... Seems that would have an link, but there's none...

Comment: Hmm, not sure what happened to the link. Anyways, here it is: http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/Eclipse_Database/Reverse_Existing_Database/index.html. Also of note, ObjectAID is apparently better than JPA; so try it out!